# Symfony2 : How to access application without typing "app.php"

Tags: .htaccess, symfony

After putting online my application (hosted by **1&1**), I can access it normally by typing **mydomain.com/app.php** (my domain is pointing to /myapp/web), but when I just type **mydomain.com**, I get an internal server error :

> Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was
>   unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator, webadmin@kundenserver.de and
>   inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might
>   have done that may have caused the error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error
>   log.
>
> Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while
>   trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

However, localhost/myapp/web works fine on my computer (without app.php)

Any idea ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok I found my answer on http://faq.1and1.fr/hebergements/htaccess/4.html

I had to add the following line to my .htaccess file :

```
RewriteBase /
```

If that can help here is my full .htaccess file :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

I've had this issue before too. In my case, it was because the web server was configured so that whenever no file was indicated (which is the case when you go to www.someurl.com instead of www.someurl.com/somefile.php), it would look for a file called `index.php`.

You might be having the same problem, since there is no `web/index.php` file. If that's the case, you just need to change the configuration.

Create a file called `.htaccess` in your `web/` directory (if it doesn't already exist). Then add (or modify) the following directive:

```
DirectoryIndex app.php
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can check your system logs. But there are some errors when you trying to run your website on a 1&1 webspace i had the same problems. It was only running when i set the PHP Version to PHP6 very strange but you can try:

1.) Clear your application cache
2.) Set your PHP Version to PHP5 or higher.
 
3.) Check your system logs they should be in a folder in your root directory.

[1&1 activate PHP5](http://amauf.de/1und1-php5-aktivieren/)

Comment: The php version is already set to 5.4 (the application works fine when adding app.php at the end of the url) and the cache is empty. I just have access to the access logs which are not really helping me...